# Why can't a mutable variable be used when a mutable reference to that variable can?

Tags: rust

I have a mutable string variable, and an immutable variable bound to a mutable reference to the mutable string variable.

```
let mut string = String::from("test");
let variable: &mut String = &mut string;
variable.push_str(" test");
string.push_str(" test");
```

This fails:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `string` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
3 |     let variable: &mut String = &mut string;
  |                                      ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
4 |     variable.push_str(" test");
5 |     string.push_str(" test");
  |     ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
6 | }
  | - first borrow ends here
```

1. Without the second variable being mutable, why am I able to call `push_str`?
2. Why am I able to call `push_str` on the second variable and not on the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting this error because mutable borrowing is exclusive:

```
let mut string = String::from("test")
let variable = &mut string;
```

Here you create a mutable reference to a variable; because mutable references imply exclusive access, it is now impossible to access the original variable, because otherwise you would be violating aliasing guarantees.

Consider this:

```
let mut string = String::from("test");
{
    let variable = &mut string;
    variable.push_str(" test");
}
string.push_str(" test");
```

This code will compile and work as intended, because the mutable reference goes out of scope before the original variable is accessed again.

You can read more about this [in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/references-and-borrowing.html#mut-references) (see [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references) link for the second edition of the book).

As for why you can call the mutating method on a non-mut variable, well, it is possible simply because the `push_str()` method accepts its receiver by `&mut`; if you already have `&mut` then it is used directly, but if you don't have one, then Rust will automatically try to create one for you, which is not possible if the variable is not `mut`:

```
let mut string = String::from("test");

string.push_str("test");
// equivalent to:
String::push_str(&mut string, "test");  // won't work if `string` is not `mut`

let variable = &mut string;
variable.push_str("test");
// [almost] equivalent to:
String::push_str(variable, "test");  // works because `variable` is already `&mut`
```

I wrote "almost" in the example above because in this case there is another step called reborrowing which basically ensures that the mutable reference can be used again after this call instead of being moved into the function call, but it doesn't really matter for this answer.

Comment: I came here after not understanding the book and this answer helped explain it further. The important part for me was the reference to String::push_str(&mut string...), where the book presumes that the reader is aware that string.push_str is implemented in that way and doesn't mention it

Answer (score 3):

The [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/mutability.html) explains question 1 pretty well:

> ```
> let mut x = 5;
> let y = &mut x;
> ```
>
> `y` is an immutable binding to a mutable reference, which means that
>   you can’t bind 'y' to something else (`y = &mut z`), but `y` can be
>   used to bind `x` to something else (`*y = 5`).

Basically, `variable.push_str(" test");` is mutating the `String` that `variable` references, but it does not affect `variable` (i.e. the binding) itself.

---

The compiler error should explain question 2.