# what's the best way to 'borrow' a struct deeply moved into other objects?

Tags: rust

I am working on a way to programmatically new struct in memory and append it to the linked list.

The way I am doing is to new a struct, new a box pointing to it and wrap it by Option. Then I need to move the tail pointer down to the newly created one.

I want to previous node owns the next node. So the tail pointer has to 
'borrow' the node.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    next: Option<Box<S>>,
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use crate::tmp::S;
    use std::borrow::Borrow;

    #[test]
    fn test_tmp() {
        let mut s1 = S { next: None };
        let mut tail = &s1;
        // potentially within a loop as a linked list has multiple nodes
        {
            let mut s2 = S { next: None };
            s1.next = Some(Box::new(s2));
//            tail = &s2;
            tail = s1.next.as_ref().unwrap();
        }
        println!("s1: {:?}", &s1);
        println!("tail: {:?}", &tail);
    }
}
```

The line commented out does not work as the owner has been moved to s1, I am fine with it.

```
tail = &s2
```

It's just so ugly but the next line works. Assuming if I have a struct that deeply wrapped and I want to borrow it. Does that mean I have to unwrap it deeply again?

```
tail = s1.next.as_ref().unwrap();
```

There must be some way to do it better. Any hints?

Comment: Since you are working with references that needs to be counted in such case, it is better to use `Rc`. Because of you want to mutate the data from the references you have, it is better to wrap it with `Mutex`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d81021bc42c250945353a89a550f0e86)

Comment: I am very new to rust. Haven't tried Rc yet. but I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the only way to do it, but it is not bad at all.

When you push a value into a linked list, you already moved the value's effective ownership (I said *effective*, because a `Box` only *effectively* owns the underlying value, but does not directly own it in terms of Safe Rust) to the last node. But how did you do it? To move `A` into `B`, you also have to own `&mut B`. And you only want to get a `&A` (or a `&mut A`). Why don't you get that from `&mut B`, since you already borrowed it anyway?

I don't understand what you really mean by "deeply wrapped". But assume we have a `head: S` and a `tail: &mut S`, where the `tail` borrows the last node of the linked list led by `head`. Now, to get an updated reference of `tail` after moving `new_tail` into `tail`, you simply change `tail` to `tail.next` (plus the `Option` and `Box` unwrapping code, but those don't affect ownership).

Have a look at this new playground code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1103d2f039c24ed6ea78408d613a4261

You should insert your data with `tail: &mut S` rather than from `head`. This is the whole point of the linked list. So to answer your question, yes, you have to borrow the moved node from its precedent node, but you already borrowed precedent node anyway, so it is nothing ugly.

---

Actually, I cheated there. I secretly swapped the last two `println!` lines. If you swap them back, you would realize that `&s1` cannot be used before the last use of `tail`, because `tail` mutably (hence exclusively) borrows something inside `s1`.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s1` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
```

So how to fix this? You can't do this directly, because you might end up with poisoned data if the thread panics while working with some mutable data. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45108086/3990767) also discusses why mutable references cannot be reused.

You might want to use a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) to hold data that you want to make [internally mutable with just an immutable borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.set). But this would be tricky. Or if you want to go multi-threaded, you might try `Mutex`.

---

But all this complexity aside, if you want real, intuitive, fast, low-level Rust, you have to work with Unsafe Rust.

Comment: I thought owns it means owns it. what's the purpose `to own &mut B`?

Comment: To own a mutable reference means to borrow something mutably. You own the reference, but not the actual value.

Comment: I am new to rust. but if it is a reference, it is not `own` but `borrow`. Am I right? then it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it is borrow. Owning a reference is a borrow. Not saying that you own the actual value. It is like when you own an address of a house, you don't actually own the house.